# Custom User profile for Django user

Tags: django

Django - Models extension Vs User Profile

I want add some custom fields like following

```
 1. ssn 
 2. is_manager  
 3. manager
```

I have 2 choices - 
**Extend AbstractBaseUser**
OR 
**Create User profile** based on signal and have OnetoOne field.
Which one is better, future proof, DB migration friendly and maintainable ?

Answer (score 2):

The Django documentation [answers this question](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) in detail:

> If you wish to store information related to `User`, you can use a `OneToOneField` to a model containing the fields for additional information. This one-to-one model is often called a profile model, as it might store non-auth related information about a site user.

In your case, the added fields do not seem to be authentication related, so your best bet is to use the user profile method. Substituting a custom user model is overkill for such purposes.

Comment: got it. I think I need a userprofile or else I will need to implement whole User model and manager.

Comment: Django noob here but that document goes on to say                           "Using a custom user model when starting a project¶

If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises:"

Comment: @EdCampion Yes, but it doesn't conflict with the statement above. It merely states that it might be good to be prepared in case the conditions change in the future.